# How to code controller to use both search and filter in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

I'm building a rails app, and I'm having some trouble getting the search function and filter option to work in unison.

```
#app/models/raffle.rb
class Raffle < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :users, through: :tickets
    
    def self.filter(filter)
        if filter
            raffle = Raffle.where(category: filter)
        else
            Raffle.all
        end
    end

    def self.search(key)
        if key.nil?
            raffle = Raffle.where(product_name: search)
        else
            keys = key.split('+')
            Raffle.where((['product_name LIKE ?'] * keys.size).join(' OR '), *keys.map{ |key| "%#{key}%" })
        end
    end
end

#app/controllers/raffles_controller.rb
  def index
      @raffles = Raffle.filter(params[:filter]) #something for search functionality here
  end

#app/views/raffles/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag(raffles_path, method: :get) do %>
<%= text_field :search, params[:search]%>
<%= submit_tag ("Search") %>
<% end %>
<%= form_tag(raffles_path, method: 'get') do %>
  <%= select_tag(:filter, options_for_select(Raffle.pluck(:category).uniq, params[:filter])) %>
  <%= submit_tag ("Filter") %>
<% end %>
```

I'm certain the issue lies in the controller, since I've tried `@raffles = Raffle.filter(params[:filter]).search(params[:search])`, but I get an error 'wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)' being triggered by the line `def self.search(key)`

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to look into AR scopes and the query object pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excerpt from your code.

```
def self.search(key)
  if key.nil?
    raffle = Raffle.where(product_name: search)
```

Once execution reaches the end of it, it calls `product_name: search`. `search` is the name of the method you've defined that requires one argument and you're passing none. I assume you wanted to call something else here.

If you would have looked at the stack trace you would have gotten it yourself.